# Why can I not pin an executable on my W: drive (= network drive) under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have a couple of exectuables on a Windows network drive mapped to the drive letter W.

Why can I not pin this executable to the taskbar ? I.e. when I run the program, right click the executables icon at the bottom , I only get the option to close the program. No other programs are there.

I have full admin rights on the pc and the network.

Any one any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft  restrict what can and what cannot be pinned to the taskbar. Thus,  if what you are trying to pin is in their 'not allowed' group, you don't get the option. Fortunately, there are ways around these restrictions, although they are less than elegant.

Essentially, the way to fool Windows 7 into allowing something to be pinned to that taskbar, which shouldn't be is by pinning something that is allowed, then changing the path. The following links describe the process:

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-pin-special-windows-shortcuts-taskbar

http://cat.pdx.edu/windows/pinning-network-items-to-the-taskbar.html

http://www.osattack.com/windows-7/using-shell-commands-to-pin-anything-you-want-to-the-windows-7-taskbar/

Comment: Thx, this is indeed the trick to do it.